# Gulp: Jscs with parameter

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint, jscs

does anybody know how to run JSCS from gulp with parameter ? I want to add **-x** options which autoformats script (see https://twitter.com/jscs_dev).
Orginally, I can type in console:

```
jscs my_Path -x
```

I want do do the same, just in gulp. My gulp code (simplify):

```
var jscs    = require('gulp-jscs');
var autoFormat = "-x";
var testStream = gulp.src('/testfolder/*.js');
return testStream.pipe(jscs());
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this configuration:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
return gulp.src('src/app.js')
    .pipe(jscs({
        fix: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src'));
});
```

Like stated here: https://github.com/jscs-dev/gulp-jscs
and use the last version of the plugin (1.6.0). I have tried it but it's not working for me. Maybe they are still fixing some problems...

Answer (score 0):

The [new autoformat feature](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/releases/tag/v1.12.0) was released one week for the version 1.12 of JSCS.

Checking the [gulp-jscs](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/blob/master/package.json) source you can see that it's still using version 1.8 of JSCS, and it's been a while since the repo has been updated. With this new feature it might be possible that in the next few days we're going to have an update for `gulp` and `grunt`.

I guess for now, you can try using [`gulp-shell`](https://github.com/sun-zheng-an/gulp-shell) or tweak the gulp-jscs source to support autoformat.

Cheers